# Using LocalDB on Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, localdb

I have been reading about LocalDB and how it can not be used in Azure Roles (since they do not persist if the role stops working) and that you should move towards either Azure SQL or Azure Storage.

However, is it possible to use the LocalDB in a Windows Azure VM? Because I do not currently have access to a Azure Account I am not able to test this myself.

Kind regards
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure VM should work fine, since it is fully persisted and largely compatible with regular Windows. Note that I'm referring to the new Azure VM feature, not the old Azure VM Role, since the VM Role was not fully persisted. Just clarifying the answer in case someone doesn't read the question too carefully.